# Can't have more than 5 items in a bootstrap contact form on an aspx page, javascript error

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm trying to convert a bootstrap based website to asp.net and all is good until I got to the contact page, which contains 6 items: name, email, a checkbox, the send button, etc.

In Visual Studio, when I try to view the page I get the error:
0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'False' is undefined

If I comment out any one of the contact items, the page loads fine.  Doesn't matter which one.

Here's a stripped out version of the master page

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Master.master.cs" Inherits="website.Master" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class='no-js' lang='en' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/headroomjs/0.5.0/headroom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="stylesheets/application-styles.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

</head>
<body class="index">
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class='navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top' role='navigation'>
</nav>
<!-- Header -->
<!-- Page Content -->
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <!-- CAROUSEL -->
        <div> 
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
        <!-- CALLOUT -->
        <!-- CONTENT - A -->
        <div>
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
        <!-- CONTENT - B -->
        <div>
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder3" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
        <!-- CONTENT - C -->
        <div>
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder4" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>

    </form>
<!-- Banner -->
<!-- Footer -->
<footer>
    <div class='container'>
        <div class='row'>
        <!-- BOTTOM NAV -->
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>

<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src='//oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js'></script>
<script src='//oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js'></script>
<![endif]-->

<script>
    if ( ($(window).height() + 300) < $(document).height() ) {
            $('#top-link-block').removeClass('hidden').affix({
                offset: { top:600 }
            });
        }
        $('.carousel').carousel({
        interval: 8000
        })
        $('#carousel-main-header .item').eq(Math.floor((Math.random() * $('.item').length))).addClass("active");
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

And here's the offending contact page, with one item (phone) commented out:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Master.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ContactUs.aspx.cs" Inherits="website.ContactUs" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="../javascripts/scripts.js"></script>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<!-- CAROUSEL -->
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server">
<!-- CONTENT - A -->
<div class='content-section-a'>
    <div class='container'>
        <div class='row contact-form'>
            <div class='col-md-4 col-xs-12'>
                <h3 class='section-heading margin-bottomgap0 med-blue'>
                Contact Us
                </h3>
                <hr class='section-heading-spacer'>
                <div class='clearfix'></div>
                <form id='contactForm' role='form'>
                    <div class='form-group'>
                        <label class='form-label' for='fullname'>Name</label>
                        <input class='form-control' id='fullname' name='fullname' placeholder='Enter Name' type='text'>
                    </div>
                    <div class='form-group'>
                        <label class='form-label' for='email'>Email</label>
                        <input class='form-control' id='email' name='email' placeholder='Enter Email' type='email'>
                    </div>
                    <%--<div class='form-group'>
                        <label class='form-label' for='phone'>Phone</label>
                        <input class='form-control' id='phone' name='phone' placeholder='Enter Phone Number' type='text'>
                    </div>--%>
                    <div class='form-group'>
                        <label class='form-label' for='description'>Description</label>
                        <textarea class='form-control' id='description' name='description' placeholder='Brief Description' rows='3'></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class='form-group'>
                        <div class='checkbox'>
                            <label>
                                <input id='contact_approval' name='contact_approval' type='checkbox' value='contact_approval'>Do you want us to contact you?</input>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='form-group'>
                        <div class='col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10'>
                            <button class='btn btn-primary contact-form-button' type='submit'>
                                <i class='fa fa-paper-plane'></i>
                                Contact Us
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class='col-md-3 col-xs-6'>
            </div>
            <div class='col-md-5 col-xs-6'>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder3" runat="server">
<!-- CONTENT - B -->
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content5" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder4" runat="server">
<!-- CONTENT - C -->
<script>
  $('#contactForm').validate({
    rules: {
      fullname: "required",
      email: {
        required: true,
        email: true
      }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      $.ajax({
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        url: "http://getsimpleform.com/messages/ajax?form_api_token=oursecrettoken",
        data: $("#contactForm").serialize()
      }).done(function() {
        //callback which can be used to show a thank you message
        //and reset the form
        window.location.href = "/thank-you";
      });
    }
  });
</script>
</asp:Content>
```

I'm certainly working above my pay grade but usually I can beat my head through this kind of wall, I mean it runs with 5, why not 6?

Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Comment: What line of the javascript is blowing up?

Comment: It says:Unhandled exception at line 297, column 346 in script block

Comment: ...which starts with 'function isUsernameFieldLoginSubForm(a,b)... and ends with ...if(:formfills"==a[b]b.fillhing)return True}return False}, and the 'return False' at the end is highlighted

Comment: tinkering more, I can paste in the form example from getbootstrap.com and duplicate a bunch of those rows and it doesn't blow up, so it's not just a quantity/space thing either.

Comment: That could be your issue. I believe you should have `true` and `false` as lower case in js.

Comment: aww carp, I just realized I had LastPass enabled on IE and that was doing it.  No idea why, still would like to know but the site runs fine in IE w/o LP and in any other browser.  My bad, sorry, thanks for looking at it.